# Azure User - End Active Session

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

- I as an Azure Admin created an Azure User in AD - User1.
- User1 is logged into Azure Portal.
- As an admin, i want to end the User1's Active Sesson of Portal with a specific Time.

How do i do that?

I have tried:

- Azure AD Condtional Access - Need Azure Premium P1 for this and it seems costly as its **per user** basis cost. I have large number of users with whom i need to set Session timeout and kill active session regularly. Which i am feeling will cost a lot for simple work. Also 1 Hour is minimum time that can be set here. Cannot set less then that.

Condtional Access Cost Details - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/active-directory/

Let me know if you know any other method or if my calculation for Azure Premium P1 is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation for Azure Active directory premium p1 is correct. Earlier it is done by using PowerShell as per this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) but this is not recommended and going to depreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there any other way to achive this requirement?

Comment: The only way that we have currently is via CA policy and it needs premium license